# question from a test

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

prove or find counterexample for the following theorem: $\forall x_1,x_2 \in (0,\frac{\pi }{2}):$$x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow  \frac{\sin x_2}{x_2}< \frac{\sin x_1}{x_1}$

Since I can't find any counterexample, it's probably a proof I need to give. So, I thought about declare a new function $f$ such that $f$:$[0,\pi/2]\to\mathbb R$, $f\left(x\right)\:=\:\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and show what the theorem want, but I'm stuck. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Is this a test that is currently going on, or is this a test that has completed?

Comment: hhhh no...it's an old test from previous years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. We want to show $f$ is decreasing on our interval. That's a job that can be handled by the derivative. You will need to know that $\tan x\gt x$ in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$. There is a geometric argument for this, or else it is another job for the derivative.

**Added:** From a comment, it seems that OP has trouble proving that $f'(x)\lt 0$ in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$. It is enough to show that $x\cos x-\sin x\lt 0$ in this interval, or equivalently (divide by $\cos x$) that $x\lt \tan x$. Let $g(x)=\tan x-x$. We have $g(0)=0$, and $g'(x)=\sec^2 x-1\gt 0$ for $x$ in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: first tnx. but how you know that tanx>x in the interval?

Comment: You are welcome. I added a proof of the $\tan x\gt x$ part. It is unfortunately a calculus proof, since the geometric argument is best done with a picture.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{0 < x_{1} < x_{2} < {\pi \over 2}}$:
$$
{\sin\pars{x_{1}} \over x_{1}}
=\int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{kx_{1}}\,\dd k
\quad >\quad 
\int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{kx_{2}}\,\dd k
={\sin\pars{x_{2}} \over x_{2}}
$$

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> {\sin\pars{x_{2}} \over x_{2}} < {\sin\pars{x_{1}} \over x_{1}}}
> $$

Comment: $0 < 2 <3$ and $0<1< 4$ doesn't imply that $2 <1$....

Comment: @N.S. Sorry. It was a real real real... mistake. I'll check it.

Comment: @N.S. Checked. Thanks.